# Declaration of a method with __attribute__((nonnull(2)))

Tags: objective-c, annotations, declaration, method-declaration

What does this `__attribute__((nonnull(2)))` mean in the following method declaration?

```
 - (void)requestShareWithObjectId:(NSString *)object 
                       completion:(void (^)(NSString *likes, NSString *reposts))completion __attribute__((nonnull(2)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It denotes that the Second parameter should not be a null pointer.

> `__attribute__((nonnull))`
>
> This function attribute specifies function parameters that are not
>   supposed to be null pointers. This enables the compiler to generate a
>   warning on encountering such a parameter.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `__attribute__((nonnull(arg-index, ...)))`
>
> Where arg-index, ... denotes the argument index list.
>
> If no argument index list is specified, all pointer arguments are
>   marked as nonnull.

References

1. [NSHipster - `__attribute__`](http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/)
2. [ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/ch04s03s09.html)
3. [Keil](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_BABDGCBG.htm)